# Why is waiting for a thread delaying updates to swing components?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, callable

I'm having trouble trying to understand why manipulating a swing component, namely a `JProgressBar`, just before waiting for a parallel task to finish.

In the following example, the progressBar will only activate its indeterminate mode after the thread finishes waiting for the result of a `Callable`, even though (I expect) that the call for `setIndeterminate(true)` happens before the waiting. Can someone explain why this happens?

```
private void thisDoesntWork(JProgressBar p){
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<String> jobResult = executor.submit(() -> aLengthyJob());

    // This happens only after the button finishes waiting. (future.get())
    // I want to know why. Shouldn't this line happen before the thread blocks?
    p.setIndeterminate(true);

    try {
        System.out.println(jobResult.get());
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {}
}

public void createAndShowGUI(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("This progress bar wont work");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton button = new JButton("Start");
    JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    frame.setSize(500, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    // Problem happens withing this button's action
    button.addActionListener((e)->{          
        thisDoesntWork(progressBar);
    });

    panel.add(button);
    panel.add(progressBar);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

private String aLengthyJob(){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
    return "Done";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test().createAndShowGUI();
}
```

---

If the waiting happens in another thread, it works as expected.

```
// Waiting in a third thread works fine
private void thisWorks(JButton b, JProgressBar p) {
    p.setIndeterminate(true);
    b.setEnabled(false);

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    Future<String> jobResult;

    jobResult = executor.submit(() -> aLengthyJob());
    executor.execute(() -> {
        try {
            System.out.println(jobResult.get());
            p.setIndeterminate(false);
            b.setEnabled(true);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {}
    });
}
```

---

Imports:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
```

Comment: The usual answer is: you somehow messed up the event dispatcher thread. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

Comment: The call to `setIndeterminate` happens before `jobResult.get()` but the progress bar can't actually update its visual appearance (which requires a repaint) until the current action event returns.

Comment: @GhostCat, that nails it, thanks

Comment: Feel free to upvote content if you got helpful information :-)

Comment: Just 'cause nobody else said it explicitly:  Your call to `thisDoesn'tWork()` is in an `ActionListener`, and an `ActionListener` always is called by the event dispatch thread (EDT).  Any time an ActionListener is called, your program will be unable to draw anything on the screen, and unable to respond to any user input until the call returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jobResult.get()` waits for the end of the other thread inside the EDT, blocking it.

> Maybe you want to at least link to some background on edt.– GhostCat

here are some resouces to read about the EDT:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

[What is the event dispatching thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484615/what-is-the-event-dispatching-thread)

Comment: Maybe you want to at least link to some background on edt. Please make sure that I didn't spoil my upvote :-)

Comment: You might also suggest [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) as a possible solution to solve the problem